# Preserve highlight when copy from Ace Editor

Tags: html, ace-editor

I am using Ace Editor in my web app. Wonder if it's possible to copy the text inside Ace Editor to clipboard with highlight. With default configurations, if I copy the selected text in Ace Editor to clipboard, it seems that only text content is copied with no html styles.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no api for this. you'll need to modify https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.5/lib/ace/keyboard/textinput.js#L290 to also set text/html mime type to some html, rendered similar to https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.5/lib/ace/layer/text.js#L442.

Also you'll need to include the css for the theme in the copied html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but this might be helpful for someone like me who stumbled upon this problem this late.

The basic idea is to get the text that is being copied and use `Ace's` tokenizer to generate HTML from it:

1. Add an event listener on the `copy`/`cut` event on the editor's container.
2. You can use `clipboard` object in event to get the data currently being copied: `event.clipboardData?.getData('text/plain')`
3. Rest steps are in code below

```js
    // get current tokenizer
    const tokenizer = aceSession.getMode().getTokenizer();
    // get `Text` object from ace , this will help in generating HTML
    const Text = ace.require('ace/layer/text').Text;
    // create a wrapper div, all your resultant HTML will come inside this 
    // also this will contain the basic HTML required to initialize the editor
    const root = document.createElement('div');
    // this is the main magic object
    const rootText = new Text(root);
    lines.forEach(line => {
      // this converts your text to tokens
      const tokens = tokenizer.getLineTokens(line, 'start') as any;
      const leadingSpacesCount = (line.match(/^\s*/) || [])[0].length;

      const lineGroupEl = document.createElement('div');
      lineGroupEl.className = 'ace_line_group';

      const lineEl = document.createElement('div');
      lineEl.className = 'ace_line';

      const spaceSpan = document.createElement('span');

      if (tokens && tokens.tokens.length) {
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Magic Happens here, this line is responsible for converting our tokens to HTML elements
        rootText.$renderSimpleLine(lineEl, tokens.tokens);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Leading spaces do not get translated to HTML, add them separately
        spaceSpan.innerHTML = '&nbsp;'.repeat(leadingSpacesCount);
        lineEl.insertBefore(spaceSpan, lineEl.children[0]);
      } else {
        spaceSpan.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        lineEl.appendChild(spaceSpan);
      }
      lineGroupEl.appendChild(lineEl);
      // `root` has a wrapper div, inside which our main div (with class "ace_layer ace_text-layer") lies
      root.children[0].appendChild(lineGroupEl);
    });
    return root.innerHTML;
```

Now finally, in your eventlistener you can wrap this with any `div` to give your own custom color to it, and put it to `clipboardData` with `text\html` mime type:

`event.clipboardData?.setData('text/html', htmlContent);`